Model won't pair to rig 2 electric boogaloo
Let's try this again. I'm very new to blender, and I'm having trouble pairing a rig to a model. Every time I try to parent with automatic weights, it will parent the objects, but the mesh won't move with the rig. The model came pre-rigged, but the original rig was very difficult to use, which is why I'm trying to replace it.

P.S. don't @ me about the tris, I know, I'm trying to fix em.

@Chris parenting with automatic weights most definitely works with separate meshes.

You have a lot of disconnected faces, select all and press M > Merge by Distance. Parent again With Automatic Weights (of course it will need some work in Weight Paint mode):

As for the bad shading, click on Clear Custom Split Normals Data:


Unfortunately, doing that makes him look like Darth down syndrome, so is there a way to fix that? Also, doing that still didn't fix the rigging issue.

It should work right away, as for the bad shading click on Clear Custom Split Normals Data

Ok, The geometry looks good now, but the mesh STILL won't move with the rig when I parent it. Am I missing a step? Also, I don't know how to manually weight paint.

Yes you must miss a step, as you see it works fine for me

I'm pairing the rig to the mesh,  is that backwards?

I'm not sure what you mean by pairing, you need to select the body in Object mode, shift selevt the armature and Ctrl P > With Automatic Weights

OH, Thanks! That fixed it!
